# Is it no-longer possible to mark questions as off-topic for unlisted reasons?

Tags: discussion

At least for someone who cannot vote to close, I can't figure out how to mark a question as off-topic that does not fit into one of the pre-defined categories?

For example
[Can a court order obtain others Facebook IP info?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46033/can-a-court-order-obtain-others-facebook-ip-info) is off-topic for this site. 
 - [image]

It is not a duplicate, unclear, too broad or opinion-based (just off-topic), so I chose off-topic...
 - [image]
But at this point there's no category for this question
 - [image]

The same is true for questions that fit on another SE site but not one of the four listed.

Is this the wrong way to go about flagging these questions?

Comment: You could choose "primarily opinion based" in this case. I have the same with close questions that aren't fit to be migrated in the first place. You need to use "other" every time.

Answer (score 8):

What we did on WordPress Stack Exchange might fit here too. Slightly changed copy from WPSE:

> This question does not appear to be about Web Applications within the scope [defined in the help center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Now we can use the proper flag/close reason, and the asker gets a helpful link.

Comment: +1 That seems like a great idea.

Comment: Seconded from [cs.se]. We were explicitly discouraged from doing that when the new close reasons were introduced, but we do need a way to say “this is just plain off-topic”.